# Fill an array of string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I have an array declared by :

```
char *tableHeuresTests[NBTEST];
```

and also a function, that fills my array.
Here is my function :

```
FILE *f = NULL; // représente un fichier en C
char tab[TAILLE]; // Chaîne de caractères qui nous servira pour la lecture ligne par ligne du fichier (~buffer de lecture)
int i = 0; // index du tableau

// TODO : Ouverture du du fichier HeuresTests.txt
f = fopen("HeuresTests.txt", "r");

// TODO :  Vérifier si le fichier a bien été ouvert. Sinon, envoyer une erreur et sortir du programme
if (!f)
{
   printf("Le fichier HeuresTests.txt n'a pas pu être lu !");
   fclose(f);
   exit(1);
}

// TODO : Lecture de toute les lignes jusqu'à la fin de fichier
while (fgets(tab, TAILLE, f) != NULL) // On lit le fichier tant qu'on ne reçoit pas d'erreur (NULL)
{
    char res[TAILLE];
    if(tab[strlen(tab) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        int j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(tab) - 1; j++){
            if(tab[j] != '\n' && tab[j] != ' ')
                res[j] = tab[j];
        }
        res[strlen(tab) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    else{
        strcpy(res, tab);
    }
    tableauDatesRetour[i] = res;
    printf("%s\n", tableauDatesRetour[i]);
    i++;
    strcpy(res, "");
}


// TODO : Fermer le fichier
fclose(f);
```

Also, here is the definition :

```
void lireFichierDates(char **tableauDatesRetour);
```

This function is supposed to read a file line by line, and fill the array (each line of the file will be added at a different index, as if the array was the file). Before adding each line to the array, I have to delete the '\n' at the end of each line.
At the end you can see a printf() that helps me looking into my array.
The reason why I do this is because after calling the function, I try to look into the array passed as argument, to see if its content is the one I'm looking for.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anClr.png) is the result

How can it be different ? Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  You don't show the code for lireFichierDates?

Comment: `tableauDatesRetour[i] = res;` : `tableauDatesRetour[i]` point to `res`(It is same buffer).

Comment: The code for lireFichierDates is the one just above. The thing is the editor displayed it strangely (the starting was outside the code block, and the end "}" too)

Comment: BLUEPIXY : You're right, so I tried a strcpy(tableauDatesRetour[i], res), but I have a SIGSEGV)

Comment: `strcpy(tableauDatesRetour[i], res)` : `tableauDatesRetour[i]` does not point to copyable area. (Before do `tableauDatesRetour[i] = malloc(strlen(res)+1);`

Comment: `strdup` creates a dynamic copy of a string. It is generally the way to go to fill an array of strings in a loop.

Comment: I did tableauDatesRetour[i] = strdup(res) and it works perfectly ! Thank you guys !